# No unique bean of type is defined, expected single bean but found 0

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

Exception which i've stated is certainly asked before. But before you mark this question as duplicate, please read the complete problem statement. As i've already tried out all other solutions available for the same problem but unfortunately neither of them hit the bulls-eye.
I'll start with the complete stack trace which is as follows :-

> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5686a031
>   11:27:18,529 ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet]
>   (MSC service thread 1-6) Context initialization failed:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'UserSessionDao': Injection of persistence
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is
>   defined: expected single bean but found 0     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:342)
>   [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
>   [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
>   [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
>   [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
>   [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
>   [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
>   [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
>   [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
>   [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]   at
>   javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is
>   defined: expected single bean but found 0     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:537)
>   [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:496)
>   [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
>   [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:630)
>   [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:339)
>   [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  ... 27 more
>
> 11:27:18,563 ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/AltSurvey]]
>   (MSC service thread 1-6) StandardWrapper.Throwable:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'UserSessionDao': Injection of persistence
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is
>   defined: expected single bean but found 0     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:342)
>   [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
>   [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
>   [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
>   [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
>   [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
>   [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
>   [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
>   [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
>   [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]   at
>   javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is
>   defined: expected single bean but found 0     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:537)
>   [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:496)
>   [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
>   [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:630)
>   [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:339)
>   [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  ... 27 more
>
> 11:27:18,615 ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/AltSurvey]]
>   (MSC service thread 1-6) Servlet /AltSurvey threw load() exception:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is
>   defined: expected single bean but found 0     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:537)
>   [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:496)
>   [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
>   [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:630)
>   [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:339)
>   [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
>   [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
>   [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
>   [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
>   [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
>   [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
>   [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
>   [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
>   [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
>   [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]   at
>   javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
>
> 11:27:18,769 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-6)
>   JBAS018210: Registering web context: /AltSurvey 11:27:18,803 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015951: Admin console
>   listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990 11:27:18,803 INFO  [org.jboss.as]
>   (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes"
>   started in 59812ms - Started 466 of 565 services (81 services are
>   passive or on-demand) 11:27:19,077 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server]
>   (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "AltSurvey.war"

please note even though i'm getting exception while deployment, but still the deploy-able is being deployed.

Now as per one of the solutions i've even configured entity manager. Please find my hibernateJpaConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">

    <bean id="surveyDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        scope="singleton" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${driver}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${password}" />
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="5" />
        <property name="autoCommitOnClose" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" depends-on="surveyDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="surveyDataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:persistence.xml" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

But this didn't work out. After that again as per one of the solutions i tried with adding below code snippet :-

Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter

in my web.xml. My Web.xml is as follows :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Document : web.xml Created on : 21 January, 2016, 11:17 AM Author : 
    Vaibhav kashyap Description: This file will contain the main servlet mappings 
    and all the app configuration entry points. -->
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">
    <context-param>
        <description>Spring configuration file</description>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:ApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <persistence-unit-ref>
        <description>
            Persistence unit description.
        </description>
        <persistence-unit-ref-name>persistence/TalentPactFormEngine_New</persistence-unit-ref-name>
        <persistence-unit-name>TalentPactFormEngine_New</persistence-unit-name>
    </persistence-unit-ref>

    <listener>
        <description>Spring Loader</description>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <!-- <filter> <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name> <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class> 
        </filter> <filter-mapping> <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name> <url-pattern>*</url-pattern> 
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> </filter-mapping> -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/fonts/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>json</extension>
        <mime-type>application/json</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

But this also didn't work out. Next solution i tried with

> context:annotation-config

enabling this through my Application context which is as follows :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="true">


    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.alt.survey.common.db.dao,com.alt.survey.common.db.service,com.alt.survey.common.db.dao,com.alt.survey.common.db.dao.impl,com.alt.survey.common.db.domain,com.alt.survey.common.db.service,com.alt.survey.common.db.service.impl" />

    <!-- Aspect for auto logging -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <bean id="surveyAudit" class="com.alt.survey.common.SurveyLogging" />
    <!-- Database configuration -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>file:C:\\Users\\vaibhav.kashyap\\Documents\\surveydbdetails\\db.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- log4j configuration -->    
    <bean id="log4jInitialization"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>C:\\Users\\vaibhav.kashyap\\Documents\\surveydbdetails\\log4j.properties</value>
                <value>30000</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Using this configuration for  my entity manager through code which is also as follows :-

```
 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "TalentPactFormEngine_New")
    protected EntityManager em;
```

which also failed.Now after trying every other solution i could find i have reached nowhere hence humbly requesting for help. Any sort of solution(new) will be highly appreciable.

Comment: And how is your `hibernateJpaConfig.xml` loaded? Magic? There is nowhere a reference to this file as such it isn't going to be loaded.

Comment: Try the first solution, but without  default-autowire="byName".

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks a lot that was of great help.The point you made was something refraining me from deploying the war. But i'm still fighting with entity manager in Dao who's properties are coming null at run time hence throwing null pointer exception.

Comment: If the bean is spring managed and you have setup annotation driven configuration the fields cannot be null as you will get an error at startup of the application. So make sure you aren't creating instances of classes yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace this:

```
   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "TalentPactFormEngine_New")
   protected EntityManager em;
```

With:

```
     @PersistenceContext(unitName = "entityManagerFactory")
     public EntityManager em;
```

Comment: Just remove `unitName` even easier. There is only a single one.

Comment: @M.Deinum ok right but for specific and maybe adding em in future